# Build error when I use patrol cli command to test native screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-patrol

Getting below build errors when i use below patrol cli command to run test

patrol test --target integration_test/example_test.dart

**Build error 1 -    Execution failed for task ':video_player_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Build error 2 -    * What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)**

Below is the code

```
void main() {
  patrolTest('demo', nativeAutomation: true, (PatrolTester $) async {
    await $.pumpWidgetAndSettle(AwesomeApp());
    // prepare network conditions
    await $.native.enableCellular();
    await $.native.disableWifi();

    // toggle system theme
    await $.native.enableDarkMode();

    // handle native location permission request dialog
    await $.native.selectFineLocation();
    await $.native.grantPermissionWhenInUse();

    // tap on the first notification
    await $.native.openNotifications();
    await $.native.tapOnNotificationByIndex(0);
  });
}
```

Build should be successful and should be able to run the test successfully.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provided code for more reference

Comment: I am facing the same problem today. Here is my error log

```bash
        1: Task failed with an exception.
        -----------
        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
        > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

        2: Task failed with an exception.
        -----------
        * What went wrong:
        java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for incompatible `gradle` and `java` versions.

To check the versions try `cd android && ./gradlew -v`

```bash
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5.1 # This version has to be supported by the JVM version below
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.x.x # or 11.x.x or 8.x.x
OS:           Mac OS X 13.4 aarch64
```

Now, install the correct jvm and set it up in `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file

1. Find out the correct `jdk` for your gradle version; say it is `openjdk@17`
2. Install JVM (`openjdk@17`)

   ```bash
   brew install openjdk@17
   # follow instructions for symbolic linking in the terminal
   ```
3. Setup environment variables

   ```bash
   export JAVA_HOME="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17"
   export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
   ```
4. Source your `.rc` file

   ```bash
   source ~/.zshrc # or ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Reopen `vscode` or `android studio` or `vim` for the updated config to take effect